# arrange block elements in a single horizontal line

Tags: html, structure, block

I dont know, either I am not that good in the art of 'search' or this topic is so so simple that nobody generally asks this but I have been searching this ever since i started my website. 
I have only four block elements on my webpage.

- The first Block element displays on the top alone
- The second, third and fourth block elements, I want arranged in a single horizontal line from next line
- At present I am using the table to do this, but its bad styling, isn't it?!
- Please tell me a way in which I can bring all those 3 block elements in the same line

At present, if I remove the table property, my block elements move to next line.
This is how it looks if i remove the table property:

^^^^^^^^^Block element: top^^^^^^^^^^^^

^^^^Block2^^^^^

^^^^Block3^^^^^

^^^^Block4^^^^^

I want block elements 2,3,4 in same line like this:
^^^^Block2^^^^^  ^^^^Block3^^^^^  ^^^^Block4^^^^^

Comment: Maybe you can try to make all the block `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

Comment: Use float for your block elements to make it appear in the same line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try display:`inline-block` or `float:left`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
      border: 1px black solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbb</div>
    <div>cccc</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
      border: 1px black solid;
      display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbb</div>
    <div>cccc</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
      border: 1px black solid;
      float: left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbb</div>
    <div>cccc</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

These are the effects on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I used inline-block