# How to bring 3 HTML elements in one line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594707/arrange-block-elements-in-a-single-horizontal-line). I want to bring these 3 things in a single line :

```
<iframe src='some link' frameborder=0 height=250 width=300 ></iframe>
<div style="width:220px;padding:10px;border:5px solid gray;margin:0px;">Just Now:</div>
<iframe src='some link' frameborder=0 height=250 width=300 ></iframe>
```

The problem is I am doing this on a wordpress page. I don't have access to(OR you can say I don't know how to) head part of the page. I want to put the code on the the same page(There are two tabs while publishing a wordpress page: visual and text, I want to put it in text tab.). I tried few things but did not work out. Can anyone help me in this?

The structure should be: Ab box -- Text Box -- Ad box
all should have equal width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each 3 HTML, use `float:left` in style.

This display each box horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

make those elements `display: inline-block`

Comment: Additional you want to add a `vertical-align` so all the elements are aligned on the same line. http://jsfiddle.net/DDKAk/1/ Used a middle alignment as example.

Comment: It makes them vertically aligned. I want to make them horizontally aligned.

Comment: @narayanpatra Do not let you fool yourself by the property name. The items are horizontally aligned because every item has the same line alignment. They are, indeed, not related to each other. But they are all aligned on the same 'height', thus makes them horizontally aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/DDKAk/2/ Hope you found this usefull.