# bootstrap layout with nvd3.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, nvd3.js

I recently started to look into d3.js. Though im pretty new in html/css/javascript; my current goal is to build a simple (static) dashboard using nvd3.js (for easier graphs) and bootstrap as layout component.

I started off with nvd3.js example "pie.html" and try to **arrange the graphs in one line** using bootstraps grid system. I got it working with d3 only using the d3noob.org example. Sadly, its not working with nvd3.

I pasted the full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="nvd3/src/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<style>

body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span5" id="area1"></div> 
    <div class="span2"> This is some random text which should be in the middle of these two charts </div>
    <div class="span5" id="area2"></div> 
</div>

<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
<!-- load the libraries -->    
<script src="nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="nvd3/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="nvd3/src/models/pie.js"></script>
<script src="nvd3/src/utils.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var testdata = [
    { 
      key: "One",
      y: 5
    },
    { 
      key: "Two",
      y: 2
    },
    { 
      key: "Three",
      y: 9
    },
    { 
      key: "Four",
      y: 7
    },
    { 
      key: "Five",
      y: 4
    },
    {
        key: "Six",
        y: 3
    }
  ];


nv.addGraph(function() {
    var width = nv.utils.windowSize().width - 40,
        height = nv.utils.windowSize().height / 2 - 40;

    var chart = nv.models.pie()
        .values(function(d) { return d })
        .width(width)
        .height(height);

    d3.select("#area1").append("svg")
        .datum([testdata])
      .transition().duration(1200)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .call(chart);

    return chart;
});

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var width = nv.utils.windowSize().width - 40,
        height = nv.utils.windowSize().height / 2 - 40;

    var chart = nv.models.pie()
        .values(function(d) { return d })
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .donut(true);

    d3.select("#area2").append("svg")
        .datum([testdata])
      .transition().duration(1200)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .call(chart);

    return chart;
});

</script>
</body>
```

What it looks like:
[image: my example]

The d3+bootstrap example: https://gist.github.com/d3noob/6a3b59149cf3ebdb3fc4

What it should look like:[image: taken from d3noob.org]

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594707/arrange-block-elements-in-a-single-horizontal-line)?

Comment: adding div to the <style> section is not working (its in one line, with border, but the graphs are missing). 
Like I mentioned in the question, I want to use bootstrap.css with its grid-system

Comment: You probably want to create two divs, displayed inline-block. Then append each nvd3js to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class "spanX" is outdated in Bootstrap 3.x

Using the class "col-xx-x" is making it work.